# How to get SimpleComboBox to display my default value

Tags: java, gxt

I have a loop that builds our questionnaires. I have a function that I call the builds the correct type. Here's the section that builds the combo box:

```
Field<?> field = null;
if (item instanceof MultipleChoiceQuestionDTO) {
  MultipleChoiceQuestionDTO multipleChoice = (MultipleChoiceQuestionDTO) item;
  SimpleComboBox<String> cmbQuestion = new SimpleComboBox<String>();
  String prompt = multipleChoice.getPrompt();
  cmbQuestion.setFieldLabel(ImageViewer.formatPrompt(prompt));
  List<String> choices = new ArrayList<String>();
  choices.add(prompt);
  for (String choice : multipleChoice.getPossibleAnswers()) {
    choices.add(choice);
  }
  cmbQuestion.add(choices);
  cmbQuestion.setEditable(false);
  cmbQuestion.setForceSelection(true);
  cmbQuestion.setSimpleValue(prompt);
  field = cmbQuestion;
}
```

I want to set the default answer to the prompt so that I can test for that later. The problem is that this is not setting the selected value on my combo box. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Do you want to select one of the item in "choice" list to be selected by default in SimpleComboBox?
OR
You want some default text to appear which prompts user to select one of the valid choices?

Comment: Both. If there's already a selection, I want to select that value. If not, I want to show default text and force a selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have an "answer". You can get the index of it from the `List<String> choices`.

```
int answerIndex = choices.indexOf(answer);
simpleComboBox.select(answerIndex);
```

Or you can directly use `simpleComboBox.select(answer);` in case of `String`

If you would like to show a default text, then you can use

```
simpleComboBox.setEmptyText("Select an answer....");
```

Comment: Select performs just like above. It selects the item, but it doesn't display in the combo box as the entry. I really don't get why this doesn't work.:(

Comment: In addition of calling `select()`, can you please try `setValue(answer)`.. Ideally it should have worked, but I see the need of calling `setValue` sometimes. Example -
`simpleComboBox.select(answerIndex); simpleComboBox.setValue(answer);`

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using below code its working

```
String answer = simpleComboBox.getValue().toString(); //or default value
simpleComboBox.setSimpleValue(answer);
```